# PHP - Dying with '?>'

Tags: php

So I have a strange and quite ambiguous question, which I can't seem to find even a vague answer to anywhere on the internet.

I've written a bunch of classes which facilitate a checkout process. The entire process works perfectly fine on my development server, but when I upload it to my client's server the code dies about halfway through (I can tell because I know which actions were and were not performed).

**Debugging the code on my development server yields no warnings or errors (and rightly so, since it WORKS locally).**

When running the website on the remote server, the code dies with '?>' as the only output. There's just way too much code to post in here, and I can't narrow it down to a specific line or even file, since I don't get any error output (and as I mentioned above, debugging it is of no use because it runs fine in the location for which I have access to a debugger).

**So tldr; my question is: Is there any generic reason for why this ?> might be echoed to the page? The nature of this text suggests that it's terminating and for some reason printing the PHP ending terminator tag?**

I have no clue. I understand that this problem is very hard to diagnose with what I've given you (and it's all I have to go on, as well) but even the slightest idea or suggestion would be infinitely helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't anything in your apache error log as well?

Comment: trailing whitespace after the `?>`?

Comment: I would first check to see if your development server and production server are running the same versions of PHP

Comment: Is that the full output? If you check the source in the browser does it show more?

Comment: @Jaitsu: that was my first thought too, but how could that output `?>`?

Comment: @braedenP, once again: Nothing in apache's error log?

Comment: @Jaitsu: Nope; that's the entire output.
@hoppa: Nope; the error log's clean.
@JLevett: My dev server's PHP 5.3.0 and the production server is running 5.2.11 (but I'm not using anything that depends on 5.3.0)

Comment: Does any php run in production?  Can you make a Hello World php file and verify that it works?

Comment: The rest of the website works fine; it's just this one portion that completely fails (which is why I'm so freaking confused lol). Still looking for some short tags I might have accidentally put in there.

Comment: Please let us know what the problem was. thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds to me that you've used short open tags (`<?` or `<?=`), and it's disabled in your production environment.

You can find out if this feature is disabled by checking the `short_open_tag` PHP configuration option.

Comment: wouldn't that cause the page to be served as download because it is not interpreted and thus not presented correctly to the browser?

Comment: If that's the reason he forgot to actually check the source of the generated page.

Comment: short_open_tag is enabled on the server, but for exactly that reason I developed the website without short tags.

Comment: @hoppa not necessarily. If only the "view" code used short tags for example, and not the "controller" code. @BraedenP So you didn't use short tags in your code? Well, this must've been the fastest seven upvotes for a wrong guess then :D - I have to say that I've had exactly these symptoms and every time not having `short_open_tags` on was the cause.

Comment: Hmm... I'll peruse through it again and have another look.

Comment: Didn't find any tags, but I did narrow the problem down to a small View file which I re-wrote, and the problem is gone. I really have no clue what the problem was, but your answer could probably help in another case like this; I'm accepting it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, you can use some echo statements to help see just how far the code is getting.  Perhaps you've got a quote mark out of place somewhere, causing the page to actually just print that part of the code.  Or maybe you've already terminated the PHP somewhere, and then you write ?> again without needing to.

In terms of that being an actual error message though, I doubt it.  My money's on some erroneous character(s).

Comment: I've tried echoing, but it refuses to output anything but that single tag.

Comment: @BraedenP In that case, Jani's solution would be the most likely.

Comment: It refuses to echo in the very first line? I don't belive that

Comment: Well obviously I'm not sure what the problem is; perhaps the PHP is running fine and Apache is messing up. But what I DO know is that lying to you wouldn't really help solve my problem, would it? :P

Comment: Ok, at this point we eliminated almost everything so I posted a weird answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the url path `/` and the web server fetches index.html or something similar and not index.php. Try to directly access it.

Comment: The entire website runs through index.php; I've set up an MVC environment, so query strings are used to direct actions. And I know it's not fetching an alternate file, because the rest of the website functions fine on the production server.

Comment: That's a lot of new info. Which MVC? How does it resolve the controller?

Comment: It's my own MVC, and the controller is resolved through a GET parameter. Nothing complex going on there. And I know this controller is being loaded, because *some* of the actions within it are being executed; then it just dies.

Comment: so you can do `echo "Here"; exit;`

Comment: Well if I terminate the script, it will output 'Here' but if I let the script run after the echo, that string is nowhere on the page. And an even more intriguing thing is that I tried wrapping the ENTIRE website in an output buffer, and the ?> still ended up on the page.

Comment: at this point you can trace down where the problem is. do a binary search with that `echo`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using zend, but they recommend not having a closing php tag in php only files (like classes) http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html

Maybe deleting the closing php tag will allow you an error message that will lead to the real problem.